# From multiple filter to single filter

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi I am new to Rails and currently working on a project my teacher gave me. 
I have this code which filters my card via checkboxes. The only problem is, that you can select multiple categories meaning that you can filter through multiple things.
But I only want this code to be able to filter one category each time.
It should only show me the cards for this category and if i select another category it should show me the corresponding cards.

Those are my filters:

```html
<div class="filter-buttons gen-width sidebar hidden-xs">
    <form id="filters">
      <% @categories.each do |categ| %>
        <div class="category-list">
          <input type="checkbox" name='<%= categ %>' id='<%= categ %>'>
          <label class="index-category" for='<%= categ %>'>
            <% if categ == "Social Media" %>
              <i class="fa fa-twitter margin-right-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% elsif categ == "Content" %>
              <i class="fa fa-pencil margin-right-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% elsif categ == "Research" %>
              <i class="fa fa-flask margin-right-10" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% else %>
              <i class="fa fa-object-group margin-right-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% end %>
          <%= categ %>
          </label>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </form>
  </div>
```

My cards are divs with the class .selectable-cards

```
<div class="selectable-card">My Cards</div>
```

And this is my Javascript for the filter

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filters input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var selectedCategoryNames = $('#filters input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
      return $(this).attr('name')
    }).toArray();  

    cards = $('.selectable-card');
    cards.hide()
    cards.each(function() {
      if (selectedCategoryNames.includes($(this).attr('data-category'))) $(this).delay(100).fadeIn(300);
    });

    if (selectedCategoryNames.length === 0) cards.show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out. All i had to do was add this line of code:

```
$('#filters input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`<input type="radio" name='category' data-category='<%=categ%> id='<%= categ %>' onclick="$('.selectable-card').hide(); $('.selectable-card[data-category=<%=categ%>]').show();">`

with the same `name` attribute instead of

`<input type="checkbox" name='<%= categ %>' id='<%= categ %>'>`

Instead of the `onclick` attribute, you can still use your jquery script with minor changes.